# How do I get custom formula conditional formulas to apply to Array results?

Tags: array-formulas, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I need to apply conditional formatting to results of an array formula to highlight any result that has the word "Installation" in it.

I have a calendar with Array formula results.  I want to highlight anything that contains the word INSTALLATION in the block.

I have used the conditional formatting custom formula of
=find("Installation",$C$2:$G:$55)
but, even though the array formula results contain Installation, the formatting is not applied.

Below is my sheet.
Thanks in advance.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1noCiboVB5_yTq9H0W_-q9goqc4E9Gq0DhcNMuXj9Kz4/edit#gid=286793601

Comment: We can't access your sheet. Please change sharing settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually need to use a custom formula for this. Conditional Formatting has an in-built function to check if the text contains a certain string.

[image]

This formula **works**, but you have to make sure that it takes precedence over your basic formula which colours cells green if they have any type of content. Basically, drag it on top of the list of active conditional formatting rules for your cells.

[image]

Comment: This does not work on the results of an array.  It only works if there is actual TEXT entered into the box.

Comment: Then please change sharing settings on your google sheet so that we can access it. It's a bit hard to help you otherwise.

Comment: My apologies on the sharing settings.  <https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1noCiboVB5_yTq9H0W_-q9goqc4E9Gq0DhcNMuXj9Kz4/edit?usp=sharing>

Comment: Amended my answer with information on why my solution did not show up in your spreadsheet. Basically, if a cell has multiple conditional formatting rules applied to it and several match their criteria, the one with the highest "priority" (aka highest in the list) gets applied. But the solution that I first posted does apply, even when you use ArrayFormulas.

Comment: Perfect answer.  I had no idea that you could alter the priority.  Thanks a ton.